# Divisible by a prime number 2, or by the prime number 2

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I want to state that "the integer 4 is divisible by a/the prime number 2."

Which is correct a or the?

Since 2 is a specific number, so "the" may be ok. But if I want to use "a prime number" as adjective, maybe "a" is ok.

Also I would like to know whether "by prime 2" is correct or not.

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way we would usually say it is

> It is divisible by **the** prime number 2.

You use the definite article because it's a specific, known prime number.  "Prime" is the adjective modifying "number 2", the noun.

> It is divisible by **a** prime number.

Means it is divisible by some *unspecified* prime number (or numbers).

"Prime 2" is not normally used (although it could be the name of a character in a science fiction movie).

Answer (score 2):

The correct form is:

> The integer 4 is divisible by the prime number 2.

This is because there is only one prime number with the value 2.

You can also say

> The integer 4 is divisible by a prime number.

This statement indicates that 4 is a multiple of a prime number without saying which one.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are **specifically** mentioning the number "**2**" it is

> Divisible by **the** prime number **2**.
>   *divisible by the number 2*